# TypeScript update object inplace

Tags: typescript

How to correctly write this in Typescript?

```
var obj = {
  kv: {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz'
  }
};

for(const k in obj.kv) {
  const v = obj.kv[k];
  obj.kv[k] = 'prefix' + v; 
  // error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
}

// desired output:
// { kv: { foo: 'prefixbar', bar: 'prefixbaz' } }
```

I want to update each item on the `obj.kv` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a bit verbose, this would be more type-friendly:

```
var obj = {
  kv: {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz'
  } as {
      [key:string]: string,
  }
};

for (const k of Object.keys(obj.kv)) {
  const v = obj.kv[k];

  // error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  // const erroneous = Math.round(v);  

  obj.kv[k] = 'prefix' + v; 
}
```

Comment: instead of `as { [key:string]: string }`, you could write `for (const k of Object.keys(obj.kv).map(k => k as keyof typeof obj.kv)) { const v = obj.kv[k]; }`. That way, you don't lose strong typing on subsequent property accesses to `obj.kv`

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor it this way:

```
var obj = {
  kv: {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz'
  }
};

for (const k of Object.keys(obj.kv))
{
  const v = (obj.kv as any)[k];
  (obj.kv as any)[k] = 'prefix' + v;
}
```

Comment: sorry I was looking at the other answer, upvoted! (still think mine is better :p)

Answer (score 2):

```
const obj = {
  kv: {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz'
  }
};

Object.entries(obj.kv).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  obj.kv[key] = `prefix${value}`; 
});
```

Note  that the `entries` method was added in ECMAScript 2016. If you do not have it available, natively or via a polyfill, you can write

```
Object.entries(obj.kv)
  .map(key => [key, obj.kv[key]])
  .forEach(([key, value]) => {
    obj.kv[key] = `prefix${value}`; 
  });
```

instead.

Comment: this is more beautiful, but TS2339 entries does not exists in ObjectConstructor

Comment: It is a fairly recent language addition. It may not be in your browser. Sorry about that

Comment: @Kokizzu I revised my answer with an explanation as well as an example that does not rely on `Object.entries` but preserves the fluent characteristics and destructuring. Thanks again for your comment.